# "Day Of Month" aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Ive been trying to get an Elasticsearch date histogram aggregation of the "Day in Month" (buckets must be from 1 to 31).

For example, say that my indexes are composed by:

```
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
-------------------
2015-02-01 11:29
2015-03-01 11:41
2015-07-15 12:45
2015-05-15 12:47
```

I'd like to be able to aggregate it by "Day in Month" in such a way that the aggregated resultset would be:

```
Day in Month   |   Count    
01             |   2
15             |   2
```

I'm rather getting:

```
Day in Month   |   Count    
01             |   1
01             |   1
15             |   1
15             |   1
```

Which I assume is aggregated per day, rather than the "day of month" that the feature here requires.

Does anybody knows how to achieve it using Date Histogram approach?

As the application here needs Time Zone support for all date dimensions, seems like the best way to go.

Comment: Why not simply using `"interval" : "day"`?

Comment: "Day" will returns several numbers "01", "02" (all way up to "31"). Each of them repeated over and over rather than aggregated the resultset.

Comment: Can you show an sample response of what you'd like to get?

Comment: Sure!
I will update my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions

1. You add another field `dayOfMonth` at indexing time and you aggregate on that field
2. You use a little `script` that will extract the day of month and aggregate on it (note: you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting))

The first solution is the preferred one as it will be more performant.

The second solution looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "day_in_month": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": "doc.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE.date.getDayOfMonth()",
        "interval": 1,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is timezone support with the [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_time_zone)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "day_in_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE",
        "interval": "day",
        "time_zone": "+02:00",
        "format": "dd",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val.

Thanks for your reply.
We user the approach number 1. Problem with both of approaches is that the don't support the time zone feature...

Comment: With approach number one, you need to apply the timezone information at the time you index `dayOfMonth`. With approach number 2, it is also possible to include timezone logic in the script. Maybe if you explain a bit more what you're timezone constraints are, we can figure something out.

Comment: Hi Val,

I can't go for the approach number one as I have too many date fields and  literally all time zones to be queried.

Number two was the one that I'm also trying. 

I have just detailed a bit more what is happing in the own question.

Thanks again for your help.